# How to use HLS timeshifting feature in iOS(AVFoundation or other 3rd party libraries) like ExoPlayer in Android?

Tags: android, ios, swift, http-live-streaming

I want to use timeshifting (for live streaming videos) feature in iOS player,But I found no library that support timeshifting. I read documents of lots of libraries like these:

1-[piemonte](https://github.com/piemonte/Player)
2-[kaltura](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-ios)

In Android, google introduce [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) that give us this feature easily. 
How can I implement this feature in iOS(by swift)? or is there any library that implement that?

Comment: do you want implement streaming video player?

Comment: @Yuyutsu no, just add these feature to the Media Player

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var liveView: UIView! //Add `UIView` on your ViewController and create @IBOutlet for it. 
        var player = AVPlayer()
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
           player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string:"Your_HLS_URL")!)
           playerViewController.player = self.player
           playerViewController.player?.play()
           self.configureChildViewController(childController: self.playerViewController, onView: self.liveView)

        }

       func configureChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, onView: UIView?) {
            var holderView = self.view
            if let onView = onView {
                holderView = onView
            }
            addChildViewController(childController)
            holderView?.addSubview(childController.view)
            constrainViewEqual(holderView: holderView!, view: childController.view)
            childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }

       func constrainViewEqual(holderView: UIView, view: UIView) {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            //pin 100 points from the top of the super
            let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal,
                                            toItem: holderView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: holderView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal,
                                             toItem: holderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: holderView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

            holderView.addConstraints([pinTop, pinBottom, pinLeft, pinRight])
        }
```