# Live stream using AVPlayer not playing in iOS 11

Tags: swift, xcode, video-streaming, avplayer, ios11

I am trying to stream a music from remote url. I am trying to run this in iOS 11 but it not play the music.

## ViewController

```
var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

var LQPlayer: AVPlayer?
let LOW_URL = URL(string: "http://someLInk.pls")! // not an original url provided at this time.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.avPlayerSetup()
    }
    
    func avPlayerSetup() {
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("AVPlayer setup error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func initPlayer() {
            LQPlayer = AVPlayer(url: LOW_URL)
            print("player allocated")
    }
    
    func deAllocPlayer() {
            LQPlayer = nil
            print("player deallocated")
    }

    @IBAction func playBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        initPlayer()
        LQPlayer?.play()
    }
    
    @IBAction func pauseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        LQPlayer?.pause()
        deAllocPlayer()
    }
}
```

I set Allow Arbitrary Loads YES in info.plist. 
Above code the URL I given is dummy. Actual url is working fine.

Comment: is it showing any error in log?

Comment: Using RTMP or HLS for live Stream ?

Comment: I think it is HLS

Comment: The error coming from AudioSession check my Log in question

Comment: Try to play that url in Safari  and check it is playing fine.

Comment: I check that in iTunes Live stream and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have HLS link?

Comment: yes I have that is LOW_URL in code

Comment: You provided  .pls  dummy url  and avplayer support  .m3u8  url for live stream

Comment: check this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261653/how-to-use-hls-timeshifting-feature-in-iosavfoundation-or-other-3rd-party-libra/46263272#46263272

Comment: I streamed with this URL in ios10 and lower. When I update my Xcode to 9 and iPhone to 11, that moment I face this issue

Comment: @Alwin In above sample code player have no view to show on screen. mean did not configure player frame.

Comment: @Alwin is it possible for you to share a  sample  audio stream url (working) so i can test it on my side.

Comment: @NaumanMalik this is url :  http://irs.internetradio.solutions:2199/tunein/hellomalayalam-lqstream.pls

Comment: @Alwin try to play and got this error : Unable to access account for hellomalayalam: Cluster host connection failure for Local server: Connection refused (111)

Comment: @NaumanMalik this url not work on safari. try to play inside iTunes (cmd+U)

Comment: Just created playlist with 0 items. and code is working fine with video stream.

Comment: @NaumanMalik can you post your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Code with Live Video Stream

```
    @IBOutlet weak var player_View: UIView!
    var LQPlayer: AVPlayer?
    let LOW_URL = URL(string:"http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8")!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.avPlayerSetup()

         LQPlayer = AVPlayer.init(url: LOW_URL)
         let avPlayerView  = AVPlayerViewController()
         avPlayerView.view.frame = self.player_View.bounds
         avPlayerView.player = LQPlayer

        self.player_View.addSubview(avPlayerView.view)

    }

    func avPlayerSetup() {

         do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
           try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("AVPlayer setup error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

    func initPlayer() {
        LQPlayer = AVPlayer(url:LOW_URL)
        print("player allocated")
    }

    func deAllocPlayer() {
        LQPlayer = nil
        print("player deallocated")
    }

    @IBAction func playBtn(_ sender: Any) {
     //   initPlayer()
        LQPlayer?.play()
    }

    @IBAction func pauseBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        LQPlayer?.pause()
        deAllocPlayer()
    }
```

Comment: sorry the problem in URL... :(